# Eclipse Project Directory does not show newly created files in the terminal

Tags: java, eclipse, terminal, console, project-explorer

So, I have an Java project in my Project-Explorer named QuizWebsite.

Now when I use my **terminal** (I'm using a mac) to go to my workspace where this project is located and create a new folder or file, my project explorer does not show the newly-created file or folder. For example in my terminal, inside the css folder of my project, if I type:

$ touch styles.css

The styles.css will not show up in my eclipse Project Explorer. Additionally, if I try to right click and create the same styles.css file using the eclipse GUI, however, it will not allow me because it says the file already exists even though I clearly cannot see it.

---

The converse of this case however is not a problem. If I use the project explorer and right click and create a styles.css file, it ends up showing inside the workspace/QuizWebsite folder in my console.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to refresh the eclipse project explorer by pressing F5 or using right click menu.

Comment: @EliezerAbate Specifically, click on the project name and then press F5.